# Hibernate list using cache? -Not updating entity attribute

Tags: mysql, hibernate, caching

I have an application that uses hibernate.
I did the following:

1. Used List to list some entities on database
2. Logged in my Mysql Database manualy and updated a field in some
   entities
3. Used List again in hibernate doing an identical query as 1

The entity that hibernate listed was not updated.
**If I close and open the application. it then shows the entity updated correctly.**

Is hibernate using some kind of cache by default?

```
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/XXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">XXXXXXXXXX</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">XXXXXXXXXX</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

Code that lists the entity:

```
        Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
        Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Solicitacao.class, "s");
        //Add some Restrictions here
        List<Solicitacao> ls = c.list();
        s.close();
```

My Session factory:

```
    public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory   sessionFactory  = null;
    static {
        // Configurações iniciais de caminho dos diretórios e arquivos
        URL url = HibernateUtil.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation();
        File myFile = null;
        try {
            myFile = new File(url.toURI());
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
        File dir = myFile.getParentFile();
        File xml = new File(dir, "hibernate.cfg.xml");
        /*
         * sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration() .configure("br/com/netradiobrasil/pcp/" +
         * "hibernate/hibernate.cfg.xml") .buildSessionFactory();
         */
        sessionFactory = new AnnotationConfiguration().configure(xml).buildSessionFactory();
    }

    public static Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.openSession();
    }
}
```

I tryed to add those lines in my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">false</property>
<property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider</property>
```

Also tryed to use: session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE)

but still didnt solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding those lines in my hibernate.cfg.xml - that enables c3p0 fixed my problem

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">40</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">100</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me guess

After executing this

```
Session s = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Criteria c = s.createCriteria(Solicitacao.class, "s");
//Add some Restrictions here
List<Solicitacao> ls = c.list();
```

You changed entries in database manually and then reran the query ? If yes then can you close the session and then rerun your code ?

Comment: Im sorry, I did close the session after the first query.......THen I create another session and reran the an identical query